# Laravel how to return object into JSON Arrays data type without keys

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, object, key

I have DB query in the Controller like this:

```
$query = User::all('id','name','email')->take(2);
$users = ["data" => $query];
return $users;
```

And get the result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Peter",
      "email": "peter@peter.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "John",
      "email": "john@john.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

But i'm expecting to get JSON Arrays data type without keys like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "1",
      "Peter",
      "peter@peter.com"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "John",
      "john@john.com"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to get this type for DataTables JSONP data source for remote domains.

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/jsonp.html

How to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `array_values` like so:

```
$query = User::all('id', 'name', 'email')->take(2);
$users = ["data" => $query->map(function (User $user) {
          return array_values($user->attributesToArray());
})];
return $users;
```

Comment: Superb. Now my "Datatables Server-side processing" integration should be easy. Thumbs up Uzair Riaz.

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```php
$query = User::all('id', 'name', 'email')->take(2);

$userValues = $query->map(function($item, $key) {
  return [
    $item['id'],
    $item['name'],
    $item['email']
  ];  
})

$users = ["data" => $userValues];

return $users;
```

```php
// result

{
  "data": [
     [
       1,
       "Amy Wilderman",
       "vrau@example.net",
     ],
     [
       2,
       "Bria Lindgren PhD",
       "trevor.armstrong@example.org",
     ],
   ]
}
```